# Why doesn't Ctrl+click work in Google's search results, and how would I give feedback to Google?

Tags: google-search

When I get search results from Google, the feature of Chrome to open the link in a new window when I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + `click` doesn't work. (I believe I've seen this occasionally in some versions of Opera as well.)

Is there a setting in my browser I can change to get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + `click` working?

I would like to give feedback to Google about this problem. Alas, I was unable to discover any way to do so when browsing through their website. How would I go about doing this?

---

EDIT: More information.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+`click` usually works, but it's failing in certain "fancy" things, like whatever Google does with its search results, or vBulletin dropdown menus.

The OS is a possible lead: the computer where I have a problem with Google is running Vista, but another computer running Windows 7, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-`click` works with Google (but still not with vBulletin dropdown menus).

Comment: Works for me. What operating system are you on? Perhaps you have an extension installed that is interfering. Does Ctrl+click work on other sites?

Comment: What operating system you using? (probably obvious, but OS X is Cmd+click)

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that AVG had hijacked my Chrome search engine (odd, because I'm *sure* I installed chrome long after AVG). The inconsistency I saw is presumably that I use a different anti-virus on my other computers.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to update your Chrome to the most recent version, as such kind of strange browser behavior has been noticed in older version, but upgrade did the trick and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + `click` works now for me.

Comment: According to the "About Google Chrome" my version is up to date. :(